# How to deal with (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1037: column at array position fetched with error 1406?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am using **Python, pandas, sqlalchemy and cx_Oracle** to execute a select query in an Oracle DB.

But I am **not able to retrieve data from a column that has type LONG**. When I remove it from the query, it runs fine, but when it is included I get **"(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1037: column at array position (*) fetched with error 1406"**

I ran into this post [How to solve error: ORA-01406 fetched column value was truncated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190584/how-to-solve-error-ora-01406-fetched-column-value-was-truncated), and read the official documentation http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01406_fetched_column_value_was_truncated.htm
The problem seems to be related to the size of the column buffer but I don't know how I would overcome it using pandas or another python library.

Is there anyway I can deal with this error?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this, I ended up executing the query via cx_Oracle and loading the result with pandas afterwards